# Get the Location of an Image from excel and Display it in textbox

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

I have a code in VB6 that displays image that comes from an excel into picturebox and here is the code for that.

```
Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
        Dim xlsBook  As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlsSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim img      As Image
        Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
        Set xlsBook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(Text1.Text)
        Set xlsSheet = xlsBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim x As Excel.Shape

        For Each x In xlsSheet.Shapes
            x.Copy
            Picture1.Picture = Clipboard.GetData(vbCFBitmap)
            Text2.Text = x.Name
        Next
```

Near the picturebox i have also a textbox, My goal is to display the cell location of the image. How can I achieve that?

Here is the update.

I have an excel format that looks like this.

[image]

Based on the code above I can display image from excel to picturebox for every object near to it. My question is it possible to get also the labels below them?

Updated.

[image]

based on what format i am using I try to add a new column below in each image called `Image Name` and put name called `IMAGE 1`... until `IMAGE 9` since i have 9 images now here is my code.

```
  Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
        Dim xlsBook  As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlsSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim img      As Image
        Dim rowlocation As Integer
        Dim columnlocation As Integer
        Dim celladdress As String

        Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
        Set xlsBook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(Text1.Text)
        Set xlsSheet = xlsBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")


        Dim x As Excel.Shape


        For Each x In xlsSheet.Shapes
            x.Copy
            Picture1.Picture = Clipboard.GetData(vbCFBitmap)
            Text2.Text = x.Name
            rowlocation = x.TopLeftCell.Row
            columnlocation = x.TopLeftCell.Column
            celladdress = Cells(rowlocation + 3, columnlocation + 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
            MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range(celladdress)

        Next
```

What happens is that when the image is selected the right `Image Name` does not come up For example in `Image 2` instead the Image Name the word `Image Name` will show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the `Shape` is contained in a single cell, you can use:

```
x.TopLeftCell.Address
```

With a picture, it's much more likely that it covers more than one cell, so you can build the complete `Range` of cells that it occupies with:

```
x.TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & x.BottomRightCell.Address
```

Comment: Probably your right the image will occupy not just one cell. I will try this and inform you once its done :)

Comment: sir can i ask you one more question?

Comment: @ShadowFiend - Knock yourself out.

Comment: It makes me look quite idiot to search what the meaning of "Knock yourself out" because I understand it quite bad but it means go for it. Sir i will edit my post so you can understand furthermore. TYSM

Comment: @ShadowFiend - Sorry, U.S. English idiom for "absolutely, try your hardest." ;-)

Comment: Sir pls see the edited question and feel free to ask for clarification

Comment: Sir what im trying to do is to get also the label of the image and transfer it in textbox the label `Gondola Type` and `No of. Unit/SQM` transfer there values in textboxes and my problem here sir that even though i have a proper format in excel i cannot guaranteed that the format will be follow (example improper way of putting the image) so i guess the best way to do is to get the label nearest to the image

Comment: @ShadowFiend - Once you have the `Range`, you can use `.Offset` ([documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx)) to access cells underneath it.  You may have to play around with it a little bit to find the cells with values in them though - it will depend on how the worksheet is structured.

Comment: Sir actually before you said that i already tried it. I will edit my post so you can understand more.

Comment: @ShadowFiend - `BottomRightCell` and `TopLeftCell` both return a `Range`, so you might want to create a bound using the `.Column` and `.Row` properties.

Comment: Sir pls see the updated and I think the final post. TYSM for a bigbig help

Comment: @ShadowFiend - See what you get for `xlsSheet.Cells(x.BottomRightCell.Row + 1, x.TopLeftCell.Column).Value`. My guess based on the screenshots is that it should be pretty close to what you're looking for - it might need some tweaking from there though.

Comment: The code below sir is what Im currently using to display the data below the current image

Comment: @ShadowFiend - Shapes aren't tied directly to column and row boundries - you can always test to see if you get `Image Name` as the value, and then get the cell to the right if you do.

Comment: Your right sir If I want, I will resize the image so it will perfectly fit in just one cell and because of that the right label will be extracted also but im sure in the future is that the user will not do that because it will consume more time . I tried your code sir and happy to say 7 matches out of 9 images

Comment: i try to adjust the image location perfectly below each label and the result is 100% match on all name but it will not be happen when user use it

Comment: are you online today?